# How to delete many documents from mongodb in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I see a problem when try remove many documents from the collection in mongo by NodeJS, although I found some question stay here(StackOverflow) same with me but it is not the prbolem that I see :(

environment:

- Database using cloud service from mongo
- Link host to connect: `...mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`
- The Collection has already some documents existed

Code

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        const user = 'tablename';

        const dbo = client.db("something");

        dbo.collection(user).deleteMany({
            'email': 'myemail'
        }, function (mongoError, result) {
            if (mongoError) {
                throw mongoError;
            }

            console.log(result);

            client.close();
        });
});
```

Error:

[image]

// Note: I setup both local and cloud service, this work fine on local but notworking with cloud service

Any helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, just simple remove `retryWrites=true` or set `retryWrites=false` in URI remote.

Thanks for your review my bad ;(